# How to make array inside in foreach loop - php?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

arrayOne + foreach loop = arrayTwo

```
<?php /* version +7 */
$input = array("teamA","teamB","teamC");
foreach($input as &$value){
    $assign = "50"; /* The data just temp */
    $data = array($value=>$assign);
}
echo $data["teamA"];
?>
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do here. What's your expected result? Some description with your question goes a long way.

Comment: Because i ask, i didn't teach, when i learned than i will writing clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for this:

```
$input = array("teamA","teamB","teamC");
$data = [];
foreach($input as $value){
    $assign = "50"; /* The data just temp */
    $data[$value] = $assign;
}

echo $data["teamA"];
```

If `$assign` is **same** for all keys:

```
$data = array_fill_keys($input, 50);
```

Comment: First make it clear from the author if he needs the same.. Your answer seems to be a static one

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$input = array("teamA","teamB","teamC");
$data = array();

foreach($input as $value){
    $assign = "50";
    $data[$value] = $assign;
}

echo $data["teamA"];

?>
```

Assigning new key-value pair to an array, can be reached via:
`$data[$value] = $assign;`, where the key is formed out of the value of initially given array `$input = array("teamA","teamB","teamC")`

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: So you're modifying `$input` while iterating over it? That doesn't make sense. The OP stores the result in a _different_ variable.

Comment: Please don't just post code-dumps. Post a description with your code, explaining why this answer is helpful and which changes were made.